# Save/Load scene state for NPC actors

Tags: unity-game-engine

All of the examples that I've seen of saving/loading a scene in Unity are either only saving/loading simple data (like the player's current health and position), or they're using a purchasable asset from the Unity store.  The logic I need is a little more complex than having just a few predefined character parameters to save, and I'd rather learn the proper way to do this instead of buying a Unity store asset, so I'm asking here.

My scenes have some actors (NPCs and enemies) that are defined in the scene in the Unity editor, and some actors that are dynamically added via script during run-time.  When the player saves, I want to record the current position/state/etc. of each actor, and then restore those actors to their last states when the player loads the game.

For the actors that defined in the Unity scene in the editor, I'll have to be able to look up the corresponding actor's data within my persisted data, and reapply that state to the actor.  One of my main struggles here is being able to identify which set of data goes to which actor, since the actors in the Unity scene often just have generic names (like `goblin`) so there's no way to tell instance A from instance B.  I thought about doing something like creating a `PersistentData` object that I can assign to each actor, and have the `PersistentData` object generate unique GUIDs for each actor.  But for something as common as saving/loading scene state, I don't want to write a bunch of custom logic if there's already something built in that'll do what I want.

The second problem I'm having is that for actors that were dynamically added to the scene, I'll have to write some code to recreate them after loading the scene.  Again, if there's already a built-in or accepted way of doing this, I don't want to write a bunch of code and reinvent a bad facsimile of an existing wheel.

My actors are all derived from `MonoBehaviour`, so I can't serialize them directly.

Is there an existing way within Unity to do this, or is there a commonly accepted way of handing this scenario?

Comment: Short answer, no, there isn't anything you can directly use. You'd have to write your own serialisation / saving code. Your approach of using your own data class is basically how everyone does it (even plugins).

Comment: @Venkat Thanks for the answer.  If that's what everyone does, then I feel better making my own solution.